# PHP - Space between sql string

Tags: php, sql

When i run my code i get this error:

WordPress-databaseerror You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fromwpiy_veosoft_crm_customerwhere Id = 957'

```
 $wpdb->prepare("select * from".$this->tables->tableCustomer()."where Id = %d", $data_id), ARRAY_A
```

I tried to make spaces between from and " and before where, but when i do that it dosent recognise that its an sql qurrie.

i want it to look like this and work, but i already tried that and i didnt

```
$wpdb->prepare("select * from ".$this->tables->tableCustomer()." where Id = %d", $data_id), ARRAY_A
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: You need the spaces, and what does this mean _it dosen't get that it's an SQL string_???

Comment: it dosent recognise that its an sql qurrie

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
$data_id = 957;
$prepare = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $this->tables->tableCustomer() . " WHERE Id = %d", $data_id);
$wpdb->get_results($prepare, ARRAY_A);
```

Hope help you.